# SMTP server to redirect to another SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp

I'm trying to make it so I can send emails using my student email address from my primary email account. My school has set up a SMTP server we can use. However, my primary email account is Protonmail which doesn't have the ability to use third party SMTP servers or the ability to add a sender email address from a custom domain if I don't own that entire domain.

The workaround I came up with is to set up an SMTP relay, where if I send an email to an address like `ieatpizza+recipient+example.com@some.relay.com` from my Protonmail account, once the relay hosted at `some.relay.com` receives this email, it'll validate the DKIM signature to ensure it is a valid signature/the sender to be my Protonmail account, then it will use my credentials on my school's SMTP server to send an email from `ieatpizza@school.edu` (I have multiple aliases from the same school) to `recipient@example.com` with the exact subject/body/content/attachments/etc of the original email. (The 'From' address should be rewritten from my Protonmail address to the school email, the 'To' address should be rewritten from the relay address to the actual 'To' address, and headers that will no longer be valid like the old DKIM signature should be deleted.)

Normally, I would write a script to copy the original SMTP packets to my school's SMTP server (with appropriate sections like addresses, passwords or signatures replaced or removed).

However, with how common "SMTP relays" are, I was wondering if there are already existing software I can use that will do this "correctly"? How would I set it up to direct the email by parsing the username of  the address and making the edits to the message as needed?